# How to create a macro in Excel365 to select a series of non-contiguous cells

Tags: excel, vba

In order to generate a line graph of solar wind shock values in MS Excel365, I attempted to manually select the shock number (sn) of 603 shock database records such that they stay selected while I also select the corresponding upstream and downstream values of Solar wind plasma and IMF from [[copied_pasted_IDE_Py_Interpreter_output.xlsm](https://stackoverflow.com)].
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvbRThajlgqAlVW5kEb3zV3dcagc?e=6Z25iU
Needless to say, I'd much prefer learning how to automate moving the value which should be beneath the "sn" from where it is, say from cell C111 to cell A111.
Any help generating such a macro in excel or script in Python will be very much appreciated.
I've tried holding the Ctrl key down after selecting the first shock number (sn) while scrolling to the next shock number. I've also tried recording a macro. I was expecting the previously selected cells to stay selected but no luck.
Thanks in advance.
P.S. I tried to include a link to the excel file (above) but having never shared a link in a post here am uncertain if it will work.

Comment: Your link needs a sign-in...  A screenshot would be useful.

Comment: Better than a screenshot, a table with a reproducible example and desired output. You can use [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) to easily copy-paste your data. Remember to change any sensible data with fake but useful ones.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Thanks. I've pasted 6 columns x 5 rows of data having 13 columns and 16.280 rows starting at row 164 into the tablesgenerator.com website. I shifted the sn value of the rows above this range manually. You will see "sn" in cell A1 with no data in the cell below it. I'm wanting to move the "7" from C2 left into A2

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Here's the result of using the tablesgenerator website:

| sn |   |   |   |   |
|---|---|---|---|---|
|   |   | 7 | 1995 | 07 |
| Spacecraft | is | wi |   |   |
| Position: | X | = | 114.8 | Re; |
|   |   |   |   |   |
| Time | windows |   |   |   |

Comment: @TimWilliams It shouldn't need a sign-in. It's shared to view, not edit, on my onedrive with anyone who clicks on the 1drv link

Comment: I can access the file now, but even seeing it I have no idea what you're trying to do.  Consider adding screenshots to clarify the task you're trying to automate, or list out step-by-step the process you're following manually.  FYI you can *edit your question* instead of adding content in comments (where it's difficult to read)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you need to do is reformat your data into a more useable format?

You can do that using VBA - for example:

```
Sub Tabulate()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, c As Range, rngOut As Range, lastRow As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Data") 'your source data
    Set c = wsData.Range("A1")
    lastRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rngOut = wb.Worksheets("Results").Range("A2") 'table starts here
    
    Do While c.Row <= lastRow
        If c.Value = "sn" Then 'checking for "sn"
            'extract and write out a set of values from this block
            rngOut.Resize(1, 5) = Array(c.Offset(1, 0).Value, _
                 c.Offset(11, 1).Value, c.Offset(11, 2).Value, _
                 c.Offset(12, 1).Value, c.Offset(12, 2).Value)
            Set rngOut = rngOut.Offset(1)
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

This assumes your source data is consistently laid out, with no variations in spacing within each block.

Comment: @TimWilliams--Thank you. Knowing next to nothing about VBA, I will thank you all kindly for trying to help and cross-post this question in stack exchange.